# Dictionary Misprint.

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english, pronunciation, word-order

I was told, (as some point in school) That Island was a misprint, and that the /s/ key had stuck to the /i/ key in printing, Turning /iland/ into /island/
Has anyone ever heard this story? the story came with a picture of keys on a (type- writer, maybe) with the /s/ and /i/ keys stuck together.

Comment: It should be noted that on conventional QUERTY/AZERTY keyboard the I and S keys (and their associated typebars) are nowhere near each other.  (Of course there have been other keyboard designs, but it seems unlikely that any would have placed I and S adjacent.)

Comment: it seems unlikely that any would have placed I and S . it was not that they were together (adjacent) when they hit the key but where the keys was when the key hit the paper, they aim for the same spot, and, sometimes get stuck together, can it happen? If you have used an older typewriter, then you know it can, Did it happen? I have no idea. was just asking if any one had herd of this story, could have been set type and they just didn't notice it. but the point was. should the spelling be iland and not island? what do you think?

Comment: first of all, what I know about language, would easily fit inside a proton. I really don't have the education or even the mental capacity to form an opinion. but I had said many times that the word island was really spelled iland.  not that I should be making statements to anyone about (well anything really). if not for Google every word i typed or at lest every other word would have been grossly misspelled.  Thank you, for taking the time to answer me.     Dan Bron & Hot Licks

Comment: @DanBron not sure when the printing press was invented in your history books. There were hundreds of printing shops by 1500 and millions of copied books. Surely England was not exactly a forerunner but London had a decent amount of printing shops. [Wiki: Printing Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press#The_Printing_Revolution)

Comment: @Helmar Thanks. Comments withdrawn as misleading and now superfluous as JEL has provided the same information and more in an answer proper.

Answer (score 1):

Although the story you heard is completely off the mark (the change from 'iland' to 'island' had nothing to do with typewriters), the change from 'iland' to 'island' was an error—insofar as a spelling change can be an error:

> **island**, *n.*
>   ....
>   **Etymology**: .... The ordinary Middle English and early modern English form was *iland, yland*. ... In 15th cent. the first part of the word began to be associated with the synonymous *ile, yle* (of French origin), and sometimes analytically written *ile-land*; and when *ile* was spelt *isle*, *iland* **erroneously** followed it as *isle-land, island*; the latter spelling became established as the current form before 1700.

["island, n.". *OED Online*. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/99986?rskey=8EgCfW&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed September 20, 2016).]

So, etymologically speaking, the change from 'iland' to 'island' was an error, but was by no stretch of the imagination a typographical error.

Comment: Of course, it has nothing to do with keys sticking together, but typographical errors can occur using a printing press. Those swept the continent in the fifteenth century. That source does not conclusively address the question if it was generally written isle or if there was a famous printed version using that spelling.

Comment: For maybe the first 200 years that printing presses existed (and millennia before that) "correct" spelling was largely up to the individual's choice -- there were no dictionaries to speak of (and computerized spell checking was even more primitive than it is today).  So how to spell "island" was up to the people setting the type, and they chose that spelling.  This is not a "typographical error", but just people doing things the way they always have.

Comment: @Helmar (and Hot Licks), I take "analytically written" to mean something like "X country has 210 hectares of ile-land and 5000 of mainland", which does conclusively address the question *etymologically*. As for whether spelling was arbitrary at the time--of course it wasn't; it was dictated by convention, just as it is now. Spelling wasn't as standardized as it is now, as is well known, but it was by no means arbitrary.

Comment: @JEL - This topic has come up before (for different words), and we've found all sorts of examples where the spelling of a word was "fluid".  In some cases a word would be spelled differently in different places in the same article.  You say that the spelling "island" was established "before 1700", but Gutenberg's press was invented around 1440, and by 1550 printing presses were fairly ubiquitous.  It wasn't until about 100 years later that reliable English dictionaries appeared (and OED not until 1928), so for 100 years printers were on their own to choose spelling.

Comment: In so far as it was an error, it was an example of hypercorrection; people didn't just get it wrong but go "ah, what it should really be is…" and then reason incorrectly. c.f. the spelling *foetus*.